# How to use Map in ReactJS in creating routes dynamically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

sample below constant file. I add a column to children propery that contains my component.
I don't know if this is okay that I am trying to pass this to my Route element using map so that I can populate the Route in react dynamically.

navLink.js

```
export const navLinks = [
  {
    id: "manage",
    title: "Manage",
    children: [
        {
            id: 'manage/DevMaintenance',
            title: 'Device Attribute Maintenance',
            component: '<DeviceAttributeMaintenance/>'
        },
        {
            id: 'manage/WaferPieceData',
            title: 'Wafer Piece Data',
            component: '<WaferPieceData/>'
        }
    ]
}
];
```

manually import those components.

I use them like this but it's not working.

```
import React from 'react'
import {Navbar, Nav, Container, NavDropdown} from 'react-bootstrap';
import { navLinks } from '../constants/index.js';
import {
    Route,
    Routes,
    Link,
    BrowserRouter,
} from "react-router-dom";

import { DeviceAttributeMaintenance } from '../pages/DeviceAttributeMaintenance.jsx';
import { WaferPieceData } from '../pages/WaferPieceData.jsx';

export const Navigation = () => {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark" expand="lg">
                <Container>
                    <Navbar.Brand href="#home">Sample</Navbar.Brand>
                    <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
                    <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                        <Nav className="ms-auto">
                            {navLinks.map((nav, index) => {
                                if (!nav.children) {
                                    return (
                                        <Nav.Link as={Link} to={`${nav.id}`}>{nav.title}</Nav.Link>
                                    );
                                } else {
                                    return (
                                        <NavDropdown title={nav.title} id="basic-nav-dropdown">
                                            {nav.children.map((dropdown, idx) => (
                                                <NavDropdown.Item as={Link} to={`${dropdown.id}`}>{dropdown.title}</NavDropdown.Item>
                                            ))}
                                        </NavDropdown>
                                    );
                                }
                            })}
                        </Nav>
                    </Navbar.Collapse>
                </Container>
            </Navbar>

            <Routes>
                {navLinks.map((nav, index) => {
                    if (!nav.children) {
                        return (
                            <Route path={`${nav.id}`} element={`${nav.component}`} /> 
                        );
                    } else {
                        return (
                            <Route path={`${nav.children.id}`} element={`${nav.children.component}`} />
                        );
                    }
                })}
            </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}
```

Tried also like this below.

```
{navLinks.map((nav, index) => {
                if (!nav.children) {
                  return (
                    <Route path={`${nav.id}`} element={`${nav.component}`} />
                    
                  );
                } else {
                  return (
                    {nav.children.map((dropdown, idx) => (
                    <Route path={`${dropdown.id}`} element={`${dropdown.component}`}></Route>
                    ))}
                  );
                 
                }
                })}
```

but an error will return

[image: errorMsg]

I'm expecting to dynamically create routes from an array of constants for us to maintain the app more easily.

Comment: You can use `.map()` exactly like how you're using it to create the nav links.

Comment: tried it sir but an error will come out upon calling the children.map. I edited the thread to include the error.

Comment: That's a syntax error; you have extra `{`/`}` in that expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import all related components in *"constant.js"* file and use them like so:

```
import { DeviceAttributeMaintenance } from '../pages/DeviceAttributeMaintenance.jsx';
import { WaferPieceData } from '../pages/WaferPieceData.jsx';

export const navLinks = [
    {
        id: "manage",
        title: "Manage",
        children: [
            {
                id: 'manage/DevMaintenance',
                title: 'Device Attribute Maintenance',
                component: <DeviceAttributeMaintenance />
            },
            {
                id: 'manage/WaferPieceData',
                title: 'Wafer Piece Data',
                component: <WaferPieceData />
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

You can then add the routes dynamically like so

```
<Routes>
    {navLinks.map((nav, index) => {
        if (!nav.children) {
            return (
                <Route path={nav.id} element={nav.component} /> 
            );
        } else {
            return nav.children.map((child, idx) => (
                <Route path={child.id} element={child.component} key={child.id}></Route>
            ));
        }
    })}
</Routes>
```